# Jquery remove entry from array based on partial match

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My array looks like this:
"MODE:ID:A:B"

```
["add:123456789:0:0", "del:99887766:0:0", "edit:1471872633890:8845:0", "add:4875125862:1523:NE"]
```

When a user deletes a row from a table a `del` entry is added to the array.

If the user has added a new entry to the table a `add` entry is added to the array.

If the user edits an entry an `edit` entry is added to the array.

The issue I have is if the user adds and then deletes the same row, I end up with two entries:

```
["add:123456789:0:0", "del:123456789:0:0"]
```

How can I get the `del` to overwrite the add (and/or) edit entry matching on the ID ?

I've tried:

```
    rows = rows.map(function(value) {
    if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return value;
    });
```

but that just replaces the entry with 'false' it doesn't delete it.

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `.filter()` not `.map()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny wouldn't that remove all instances of the element though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) will work as you expect. `undefined` or `null` return values will not be mapped.

```
rows = $.map(rows, function(value) {
    if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return value;
    });
```

jQuery map callback function can return:

- the translated value, which will be mapped to the resulting array
- null or undefined, to remove the item
- an array of values, which will
  be flattened into the full array

Comment: using this return false into the array `[false, "del:1471958467387:0:0"]`

Comment: Yeah, I had an error. `return undefined` not `false`

Comment: This seems to be working and follows a similar approach to how I was try to do it.. so I understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and split an item for the check and update and reassemble the item for an assingment to the element.

This proposal expects only one item with the given `id`.

```js
var data = ["add:123456789:0:0", "del:99887766:0:0", "edit:1471872633890:8845:0", "add:4875125862:1523:NE"],
    id = '123456789';

data.some(function (a, i, aa) {
    var item = a.split(':')
    if (item[1] === id) {
        item[0] = "del";
        aa[i] = item.join(':');
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a filter in the end:

```
rows = rows.map(function(value) {
    if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    return value;
    })
.filter( function(item) {return item;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
rows = $.map(rows, function(value){
    if(value.indexOf(id) > -1){
        return 'del:' + id;
    }
}
```